# Is it ok to write the American spelling of words on IELTS?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, ielts

I took the IELTS exam a week ago and on the way home I started to remember to have written 'color' on one answer and then it came to my mind: Do I loose marks if I write the American spelling of words on the IELTS exam?
I did not see anywhere making it clear whether or not it is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official IELTS site](https://www.ielts.org/what-is-ielts/ielts-introduction) states (bolding is mine):

> IELTS treats all test takers with the utmost fairness and respect by actively avoiding cultural bias, and  **accepting all standard varieties of native-speaker English**, including North American, British, Australian and New Zealand English.

**UPDATE**

As the commenters suggest below, it should be noted that your style has to be **consistent**. Once having chosen a particular standard, you must adhere to it.

Comment: @luizfzs Back when I was taking it (some 2 years ago) I remember there was a tiny disclaimer on the pages of the actual exam that you have to stick to just one (but any) variety of spelling throughout the exam. I'm not sure if that causes one to lose points, but you still might want to be more careful next time.

Comment: To paraphrase what @Gallifreyan says: if you wrote _color_, _traveled_ and _realize_ throughout, you’ll be fine; if you wrote _colour_, _travelled_, and _realise_ throughout, you’ll also be fine. But if you wrote _color_, but _travelled_ and _realise_, you’ll probably get a mark off, because that combination does not belong to any “standard varieties of native-speaker English”. And if you wrote _color_ in one place and _colour_ in another, you’ll almost certainly be marked down, because that’s just inconsistent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've done it

Comment: Yes, I saw but I can't upvote twice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write either *color* or *colour*, both are correct.
I also gave the exam on 3rd June 2017 in Teaneck, and asked the invigilator the same. She told me you can write either, it's fine.